# Flink-Read Dynamic Json string from Kafka and load to Hbase

Tags: apache-kafka, hbase, apache-flink

Just started exploring Flink, whether that's suitable for our below use case. Before starting, i just want your valuable inputs.

1. Dynamic Json string should be read from Kafka. Each event Json can
   be different
2. Json string should be inferred. Json schema is complex nested.
3. Json schema should be flattened
4. Load to Hbase

I want to achieve the above functionality using Scala. Can that be accomplished?

Flink Documentation is very limited. I cant find much.Guide me how to start with.

Thanks

Comment: Overall this shouldn't be difficult, but your requirements for a `DeserializationSchema` to use with Kafka and JSON aren't very clear. What have you tried?

Comment: Kafka will give Json string..Flink need to infer the json schema and flatten it, before loading to Hbase. Tried with Spark.Spark structured streaming doesn't support real time json infer, whereas sparking streaming support does. So implemented this logic in spark streaming. But, need to check the performance. But, what i believe is, Flink is more advanced in performance and features than spark. Thought to give a try...